# How do I close a multithreaded server?

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

So I have a program that clients can enter any type of tasks and other clients can check it as well but I don't know how to close the loop that tries to accept new connetions to the server.
What I want is when I close the last client running using a command I wrote I want the server to close as well.

Can anyone help?

```
public class TaskListServer {
    public static List<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String uniqueString(){
        return String.join(", ", taskList);
    }

    public static void addTasks(String task) {
        taskList.add(task);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4242);
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ThreadedServer clientThread = new ThreadedServer(clientSocket);
                new Thread(clientThread).start();
            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sc.close();
    }
```

Comment: You want the server to close when you finish *your* last command, even though other users may also be logged into the server and processing commands?

Comment: Yes, for now i just want him to check if there is any clients connections only if there is a connection running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an infinity loop (`while(true)`).

```
private static boolean acceptNewClients = true;
    
    public static void flipAcceptNewClients() {
        acceptNewClients = !acceptNewClients;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* your code here */
        while (acceptNewClients) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            ThreadedServer clientThread = new ThreadedServer(clientSocket);
            new Thread(clientThread).start();
        }
        /* your code here */
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223563/discussion-on-answer-by-paladin-how-do-i-close-a-multithreaded-server).